# PHP two values on array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make mini shop.
How to add one key, two values to an array?
I tried this:

```
array(
"My Item" => "images/photo.jpg" => "9,99",
"T-Shirt" => "images/tshirt.jpg" => "19,99");
```

(I do not want use database)

Comment: not possible. pretty much every array in the universe is `key=>value`. if you want multiple values, then use arrays-of-arrays `key=>array(value,value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
array(
    "My Item" => array("images/photo.jpg", "9,99"),
    "T-Shirt" => array("images/tshirt.jpg", "19,99")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question is invalid array syntax. This would be valid:

```
array(
"My Item" => array("images/photo.jpg", "9,99"),
"T-Shirt" => array("images/tshirt.jpg", "19,99"));
```

Remember that this is equivalent to

```
array(
"My Item" => array(0 => "images/photo.jpg", 1 => "9,99"),
"T-Shirt" => array(0 => "images/tshirt.jpg", 1 => "19,99"));
```

It may be easier for you to use this array in subsequent code if you use string keys instead. This is optional, of course.

```
array(
"My Item" => array('image' => "images/photo.jpg", 'price' => "9,99"),
"T-Shirt" => array('image' => "images/tshirt.jpg", 'price' => "19,99"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 5.4 is there a great short syntax:

```
$articles = [
   'art1' => ['images/photo.jpg', 9.99],
   'art2' => ['images/tshirt.jpg', 19.99]
];
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Generally:

- Choose handy key names (I prefer no spaces)
- Store prices as number without quotes, so you can format them easy

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = array('1st', '1.1');
$array[] = array('2nd', '1.2');
$array[] = array('3rd', '1.3');
```